# F# Generate SQL from CSV

Tags: sql, f#, scripting

I have recently been learning F# and functional programming.  One application I have found very useful is generating SQL inserts for a data load from a CSV (or excel table) with some associated ID's.

The following code is my result, which I believe I will find very handy in the future.  I thought others could also benefit from this and I welcome suggestions and other scripts which people have found invaluable in their collection:

```
// Returns some dataload SQL for area mapping.
open System
open System.IO

// Read and split CSV into lists
let map_ngo_area = File.ReadAllLines(@"P:\MY_TABLE.csv") 
                        |> Array.to_list
                        |> List.map(fun x -> (x.Split([|','|]) 
                                                |> Array.map(fun y -> y.Trim())) 
                                                |> Array.to_list)

// Output Formatting function
let format_sql_record = "INSERT INTO MyTable
     (ID, REF1_ID, REF2_ID, CreatedUser, CreatedDateTime, LastModifiedUser, LastModifiedDateTime)
     VALUES
     ( {0}, {1}, {2}, 'system', getDate(), 'system', getDate() )"

 // Generate the SQL for the given list.  
let generate_sql list = list |> List.mapi(fun index row -> 
                                            match row with
                                                | [ngo_id; area_id] -> String.Format(format_sql_record, ((int index)+1), ngo_id, area_id) |> printfn "%s"
                                                | _ -> printfn "")

// Main Execution
map_ngo_area |> generate_sql |> ignore

// End of program, pause to view console output.
System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Any suggestions on improving my F# code or process? Comments also welcome, as I am fairly new at this paradigm and shifting thinking is not as forthcoming as I expected.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions:

- Don't use `List.mapi` with functions that return `unit`, since there's not much you can do with the resulting `unit list`.  You should use `List.iteri` instead, which will allow you to omit the `|> ignore` at the end of your main execution section.
- Going further, rather than having `generate_sql` print the generated lines one at a time, it might be better to generate a list of strings instead.  Note that in this case, you would go back to using `List.mapi` since the function that you apply would return a result for each line.
- Use F#'s print formatting rather than `String.Format`.  For instance rather than having `format_sql_record` be a string, have it be a function of type `int->string->string->string`: `let format_sql_record = sprintf "INSERT INTO ... VALUES (%i, %s, %s, ...)"`
- Depending on the version of F# that you're using, you should probably be using the renamed function `Array.toList` instead of `Array.to_list`, since that's the name that will be used in the final release of F#.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pattern matching on arrays too:

```
let map_ngo_area = File.ReadAllLines(@"P:\MY_TABLE.csv") 
                    |> Array.to_list
                    |> List.map(fun x -> (x.Split([|','|]) 
                                            |> Array.map(fun y -> y.Trim())) 

let generate_sql list = list |> List.mapi(fun index row -> 
                                            match row with
                                            | [| ngo_id; area_id |] -> printfn ...
                                            | _ -> printfn "")
```